# Can anyone please tell me java spring data mongodb can I use BasicDBObject as property in domain class Employee

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

```
@Document
public class Employee{
    private BasicDBObject height;
    public BasicDBObject getHeight() {
        return this.height;
    }

    public void setHeight(final BasicDBObject height) {
        this.height = height;
    } 

}
```

In mongodb Employee document I am storing **height** data like this

```
"height" : {
    "fromHeightPref" : {
        "id" : "5063114bd386d8fadbd6b009",
        "value" : "5Ft-2In",
        "category" : 157
    },
    "toHeightPref" : {
        "id" : "5063114bd386d8fadbd6b012",
        "value" : "5Ft-5In",
        "category" : 165
    }
}
```

so In java domain class can I use this BasicDBObject height property like above. If not please anyone assist me to make it better. In am new to java and mongodb

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee {
    private String name;
    private List<Height> height;
}

class Height {
    private HeightPref fromHeightPref;
    private HeightPref toHeightPref;
}

class HeightPref {
    private String id;
    private String value;
    private String category;
}
```

While fetching employee from mongo you can do the following

```
DBObject employeeDBObj; //fetched from mongodb

BasicDBObject heightDBObj = employeeDBObj.get("height");
BasicDBObject fromHeightPref = heightDBObj.get("fromHeightPref");
BasicDBObject toHeightPref = heightDBObj.get("toHeightPref");

Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setName(String.valueOf(employeeDBObj.get("name")));

Height height = new Height();
HeightPref fromHeightPref = new HeightPref();
HeightPref toHeightPref = new HeightPref();

fromHeightPref.setId(String.valueOf(fromHeightPref.get("id"))
fromHeightPref.setValue(String.valueOf(fromHeightPref.get("value"))
fromHeightPref.setCategory(String.valueOf(fromHeightPref.get("category"))

//same with toHeightPref

height.setFromHeightPref(fromHeightPref);
height.setToHeightPref(toHeightPref);

employee.setHeight(height)
```